# cabal update fails to download the archive file

Tags: haskell, cabal

I upgraded my Haskell platform to and copied the new cabal binary to my ~/.cabal/bin folder in my MacOS.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.1

$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.2.0
using version 1.22.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Now, when I try to update the package list, I get the following error:

```
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Failed to download
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz : ErrorMisc "Error
HTTP code: 400"
```

I can download the 00-index.tar.gz file using my browser, but cabal fails to download it. What can be the problem?

Comment: you updated your GHC right? (because AFAIK there is not Haskell Platform with GHC 7.10 yet) - if so how did you do it? You might want to nuke your installation and restart with just the new GHC/Cabal and add just the packages you really need - but possibly there will be someone who can say you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: You don't have a proxy that your browser would know about but not Cabal?

Comment: @JPMoresmau thanks, a vpn client installed in my PC  is the reason. i closed it and cabal updated successfuly.